# WPF TreeView - adding TreeNode with children

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treenode

I have **TreeNode** object [*namespace System.Windows.Forms*] and I have WPF **TreeView** Control.

I'm trying to populate this wpf control with the TreeNode data by this code:

```
   public partial class TreeWindow : Window
    {
        public TreeWindow(TreeNode node)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            treeView.Items.Add(node);
        }
    }
```

This TreeNode contains many children in a tree hierarchy.

.e.g :

-Parent

--Child

----Child

--Child

...

But In the wpf window I'm getting only the parent node.
without the expand/collapse buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert them to `System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem` first.

```
public TreeWindow(TreeNode node)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    treeView.Items.Add(ConvertToWpf(node));
}


TreeViewItem ConvertToWpf(TreeNode node)
{
    var wpfItem = new TreeViewItem();
    wpfItem.Header = node.Text;
    foreach(var child in node.Nodes)
    {
         wpfItem.Items.Add(ConvertToWpf(child));
    }
    return wpfItem;
}
```

Comment: Only one small issue - at the leaf nodes, I'm still getting the 'Expand' button

Comment: I think that's because TreeViewItem has the expander button. if you use another control as leaf items (like button) the problem is solved